# Plotting line fit

Tags: plotting, fitting, data

```
data = {{4, 4}, {4, 25}, {25, 63}, {63, 147}, {147, 285}, {285, 
    361}, {361, 405}, {405, 471}, {471, 420}, {420, 430}, {430, 
    420}, {420, 475}, {475, 435}, {435, 480}};
```

I have data like above , data Pn as x and P(n+1) as y

I am using `Fit` to make the plot, but the plot only shown dots not line:

```
line = Fit[data, {1, x}, x] 
parabola = Fit[data, {1, x, x^2}, x]
```

im trying to compare the linear and quadratic data on my cases

Comment: Doesn't Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot[{line, parabola}, {x, 0, 500}]] help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning comment into answer:

Try:

```
Show[
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red] 
 ,Plot[{line, parabola}, {x, 0, 500}]
]
```

Btw, I quickly checked and this code can be found in the documentation, I suggest you to look into that when you have a problem as it helps a lot, in particular if you have just started programming in Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks its work, but i already try it before with Show[ListPlot[Data, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot[{line, parabola}, {x, 0, 5}]] but it wasn't work , can you tell me why?

Comment: The problem is the range of the plot: in your code you copy-pasted the definition from the documentation, but you didn't change the range. Indeed, you are plotting values from 0 to 5, while your data span from 4 to 435. That's why you need to plot the functions over a much larger range (in my code, I used 0 to 500 as you can see).
Hope the explanation makes sense, feel free to ask if you have any doubt about it.

Comment: i see, thank you ~~~~